# Knockout JS: observableArray.splice(0) not cloning array?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

#### Background

I cannot seem to lose the reference to the original array I'm trying to clone. To illustrate my problem concretely, suppose I have the following.

> **JSBin**:  http://jsbin.com/fehoq/168/edit

```
student.scores:  Array[3]
    0: 12
    1: 97
    2: 81
```

My `dropLowestScores` method then intends to find the two lowest values in the `scores` array, *copies* them and put them in property `lowest`.

```
 student.lowest:  Array[2]
    0: 12
    1: 81
```

Unfortunately, while I get the correct values in `lowest`, rather than copying them from `scores`, they are spliced. Not only that, but all values from my original array are depleted.

```
student.scores:  Array[0]
```

This might make sense, given that I'm calling knockout's `splice` method, **but** I'm calling it on a copy of the `scores` array where I first called `splice(0)`! I'm not sure if it matters, but the observable array I am splicing consists of observable numbers.

See the script below for details, or the JSBin above for the full thing.

Note that `student` is just the model I'm working with.

#### JS

```
this.dropLowestScores = function() {

    // find lowest scores for each student
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(_this.students(), function(student){

        //sporting function for observable values in array
        var comparator = function(a,b){
          if(a()<b()){
            return -1;
          } else if(a() > b()){
            return 1;
          } else {
            return 0;
          }
        };                 

        // tmp is a sorted clone of scores
        var tmp = student.scores().sort(comparator).splice(0);

        // set lowest to last two values in tmp array
        student.lowest = tmp.splice((tmp.length-2),tmp.length);

        // see what I'm getting
        console.log(student.fullName());
        console.log('student lowest: ' + student.lowest.length);
        console.log('student scores: ' + student.scores().length);
    });
};
```

#### Update

As edhedges pointed out, `slice` is the correct method. The `comparator` was also sorting opposite of how I intended.

A further point is that I cannot sort until `tmp` is created, else it updates the view, which I **do not** desire.

The final version should look like the following.

```
this.dropLowestScores = function() {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(_this.students(), function(student){
        var comparator = function(a,b){
          if(a()<b()){
            return 1;
          } else if(a() > b()){
            return -1;
          } else {
            return 0;
          }
        };       
        var tmp = student.scores().sort(comparator).slice(0);
        student.lowest = tmp.splice((tmp.length-2),tmp.length-1);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue you are having here is that you called `splice` and should have called `slice`.

As you can see [slice](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#slice) is what you are trying to accomplish, but you used [splice](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#pop-push-shift-unshift-reverse-sort-splice) with no second argument so your array was getting wiped.

Once this was fixed you still had a problem in your `comparator` function. You were returning the two highest not the two lowest.

```
// updated dropLowestScores
this.dropLowestScores = function() {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(_this.students(), function(student){
        var comparator = function(a,b){
          if(a()<b()){
            return 1;
          } else if(a() > b()){
            return -1;
          } else {
            return 0;
          }
        };                 
        var tmp = student.scores.slice(0).sort(comparator);
        student.lowest = tmp.splice((tmp.length-2),tmp.length);
        console.log(ko.toJSON(student.lowest));
        console.log(ko.toJSON(student.scores));
    });
};
```

Comment: For future viewers, I added a note to my original post.